# How to add a new custom font in python-pptx?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, fonts, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have an otf/ttf file for custom font from my organization. I am trying to generate a ppt and I need to configure/ register this new font in the ppt.

I have attached a sample code where I need to show the title and other text in the new font provided by otf/ttf file.

I tried to research in the documents, I could not find anything. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches,Pt
from pptx.enum.text import PP_ALIGN, MSO_AUTO_SIZE
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

#Org-Sans-Text-Regular.otf
#Org-Sans-Text-Regular.ttf

ppt = Presentation()
slide_layout = ppt.slide_layouts[6]
slide = ppt.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

text_box1 = slide.shapes.add_textbox(Inches(0), Inches(0.15), Inches(10), Inches(0.35))

tf1 = text_box1.text_frame
tf1.paragraphs[0].text = 'Sample Title'
tf1.paragraphs[0].alignment = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
tf1.paragraphs[0].font.bold = True

ppt.save('test.pptx')
```

Comment: Could you clarify the issue, is it that you don't know how to change a font in python-pptx in general, or can you change to already installed fonts but not to this particular font? Can you show the code you currently use/try to use to change the font, and explain what happens with that code? Do you want to embed the font in the pptx file, or should it be installed on the machines by the script, or is it expected that the font is already installed? Which operating system do you use and does the script have administrator privileges?

Comment: Please find the code attached in the main post. I need to show the text in the new font, how do I do this?

Comment: Thanks for the update. About the StackOverflow interface: there are two ways of adding code, one is with the snippet tool that you used and another one is by copy-pasting the code in the question text and then use the code formatting button `{ }` (or surround with triple backticks/code fences). The first way is only intended for html/css/javascript code, so it would be better to use the second way to get proper code formatting. Also it is not needed to put extra information like "**Edited" or "any help will be appreciated" in the post.

Comment: That said, could you also answer all the other questions in my first comment, besides providing the code itself?

Comment: I can change the font to already installed font using python-pptx but I do not require that. what I need is to use this new font in otf/ttf file.
I am running the jupyter notebook in organization's cloud so I do not want to install the new font in my system, and I need to embed this new font in ppt by importing the otf/ttf file somehow.
I am using windows OS but the terminal on the cloud is bash. I hope I answered all the questions. Please let me know otherwise. Thank you.

Comment: Also I changed the formatting of the code. Thank you for guiding.